# Photologue not showing images or thumbnails

Tags: photologue

I am not able to get photologue to show the images.    What am I doing wrong?

#### development environment

- django 2.1
- python 3.5
- osx, virtual_env, recent pip

#### settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mst/media/')
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
```

#### urls

```
urlpatterns += [
    ...
    url(r'^photologue/', include('photologue.urls', namespace='photologue')),
]
```

model

```
from photologue.models import Photo, Gallery

class PhotoExtended(models.Model):
    photo = models.OneToOneField(Photo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='photo')
    related_model = models.ForeignKey(MyModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.photo.title

class GalleryExtended(models.Model):
    gallery = models.OneToOneField(Gallery, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='gallery')
    related_model = models.ForeignKey(MyModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.gallery.title
```

#### class based view

```
class MyModelList(ListView):
    model = MyModel
    template_name = "pictures.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['photos'] = PhotoExtended.objects.all()
        context['galleries'] = GalleryExtended.objects.all()
        return context
```

#### template (pictures.html):

```
{% block content %}
    <ul>
        {% for photoExtended in photos %}
            <li>{{ photoExtended.photo.get_absolute_url }}</li>
            <li>{{ photoExtended.photo.image }}</li>
            <img src="/{{ photoExtended.photo.image }}" alt="{{ p.photo.title }}">
        {% endfor %}
        {% for gallery in galleries %}
          <li></li>
        {% endfor %}
```

#### shell response (per [docs](https://django-photologue.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pages/installation.html#that-troublesome-pillow))

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>>
```

#### notes

I migrated the database, and see the data in the database, and everything looks correct.

---

---

---

## page renderings

### photologue urls:

A single photo

### [image: a single image]

the list of the photos
[image: a list of photos]

### and the direct accessing of the image: (ra is the name in photologue, but em.jpeg is the file name)

[image: direct access of the image]

### and my view directly:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The template was wrong/outdated from an older version.  Here is the correct usage in the template for an image within a list of images of type photologueExtended:

```
{% for photoExtended in photos %}            
    <!-- The link to the photologue template page with the photo and its gallery(s)-->
    <a href="{{ photoExtended.photo.get_absolute_url }}">Link to page</a>
    <!-- The src link to the image thumbnail itself in the media url-->
    <img src="{{ photoExtended.photo.get_thumbnail_url }}" />
    <!-- The src link to the image itself in the media url-->
    <img src="{{ photoExtended.photo.get_display_url }}" />
    <!-- The photologue image's title/description/etc… -->
    {{ photoExtended.photo.title }} <br>
    {{ photoExtended.photo.description }} <br>
{% endfor %}
```

Also:

the url catchall in the main project `urls.py` was incorrect, and should be:

```
url(r'^$', indexView, name='indexView'),
```